# Simulate a button submit in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way to simulate a button submit in oracle apex within a process?

Comment: can you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In the apex process you can have a check like if :request = 'SUBMIT' then

Write your pl/SQL processing statements and
If you want to redirect to any page / URL then have the below example statement
OWA_UTIL.redirect_url('f?p=103:4')

End if;

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? I don't think there is a way to send a button submit via the Apex API, but based on what your requirements are, the same effect might be obtained.